# Simple algorithm for online outlier detection of a generic time series

Tags: math, statistics, real-time, time-series

I am working with a large amount of time series.
These time series are basically network measurements coming every 10 minutes, and some of them are periodic (i.e. the bandwidth), while some other aren't (i.e. the amount of routing traffic).

I would like a simple algorithm for doing an online "outlier detection". Basically, I want to keep in memory (or on disk) the whole historical data for each time series, and I want to detect any outlier in a live scenario (each time a new sample is captured).
What is the best way to achieve these results?

I'm currently using a moving average in order to remove some noise, but then what next? Simple things like standard deviation, mad, ... against the whole data set doesn't work well (I can't assume the time series are stationary), and I would like something more "accurate", ideally a black box like:

```
double outlier_detection(double* vector, double value);
```

where vector is the array of double containing the historical data, and the return value is the anomaly score for the new sample "value" .

Comment: You might also want to try asking at stats.stackexchange.com - it's StackOverflow strictly for statistics questions.

Comment: There have now been several answers to this question posted at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series

Answer (score 9):

This is a big and complex subject, and the answer will depend on (a) how much effort you want to invest in this and (b) how effective you want your outlier detection to be. One possible approach is [adaptive filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_filter), which is typically used for applications like noise cancelling headphones, etc. You have a filter which constantly adapts to the input signal, effectively matching its filter coefficients to a hypothetical short term model of the signal source, thereby reducing mean square error output. This then gives you a low level output signal (the residual error) *except* for when you get an outlier, which will result in a spike, which will be easy to detect (threshold). Read up on [adaptive filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_filter), [LMS filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter), etc, if you're serious about this kind of technique.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems like a good approach, but what if the signal exhibits a high seasonality (i.e. a lot of network measurements are characterized by a daily and weekly pattern at the same time, for example night vs day or weekend vs working days)? Will an adaptive filter be able to model this aspect? In my ideal world, I would like to detect a peak of traffic happening during the sunday morning, while the same value might be completely normal on Monday.

Comment: So long as you have enough terms in your filter to model the various periodicities then it should just work - the adaptive filter will remove these frequencies leaving just residual noise.

Comment: Thank you again, I would like to try an algorithm based on this stuff. Do you know if there are some general purpose libraries to do a preliminary simulation of this method, before doing a real implementation (which probably takes some time)?

Comment: You can probably prototype this quite quickly and easily in MATLAB (or a free clone like Octave). See e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3649-lms-algorithm-demo

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the scheme below, which should be implementable in a day or so:

#### Training

- Collect as many samples as you can hold in memory
- Remove obvious outliers using the standard deviation for each attribute
- Calculate and store the correlation matrix and also the mean of each attribute
- Calculate and store the [Mahalanobis distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) of all your samples

#### Calculating "outlierness":

For the single sample of which you want to know its "outlierness":

- Retrieve the means, covariance matrix and [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)s from training
- Calculate the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) "d" for your sample
- Return the percentile in which "d" falls (using the Mahalanobis distances from training)

That will be your outlier score: 100% is an extreme outlier.

---

PS. In calculating the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance), use the correlation matrix, not the covariance matrix. This is more robust if the sample measurements vary in unit and number.