# Down-to-earth introduction to time-series for a programmer

Tags: time-series, article

I'm a programmer who is interested in processing and analyzing time-series data. I  know basic statistics and math, but I'm afraid that's all.
Can you please recommend good books and/or articles that **does not require Ph.D. to understand them**? 
As for my concrete tasks - I want to be able to spot trends, eliminate outliers, be able to make predictions and calculate stats over a range of values. We have quite a bit of events coming off our systems. 
I started reading "Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting" by Brockwell and Davis - and I'm completely lost in math. 
**update on outliers** by outliers I mean data points that doesn't necessarily make sense. e.g. the exchange rate is 1.5$(+-10 cents) for a pound on average, but a guy around the corner offers 1.09$ and says he's completely legit.

Comment: can you explain votes to close? may be there's a question I haven't found?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the NIST Engineering Statistics Handbook's [chapter on time series](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc4.htm) to be a simple and clear introduction to basic time series modeling. It discusses exponential smoothing, auto-regressive, moving average, and eventually ARMA time series modeling. These can be used for trend analysis and possibly prediction, subject to validation.

Outlier/anomaly detection is a much different task; the NIST book doesn't have much on this. It would be helpful to know what kind of outliers you are trying to detect.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through numerous books and articles and here are my findings. May be they will help others like me.
Regarding theory - I found an article [An Introductory Study on Time Series Modeling and Forecasting](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6613) very well written. That doesn't mean I understood all of its contents, but it's a really good overview of available time series models. 
If you're like me and like to see some actual code - there's [article series on QuantStart](https://www.quantstart.com/articles#time-series-analysis). Examples are in R, but I guess many of them are portable to Python.

I can highly recommend [QuantStart blog](https://www.quantstart.com/) by Michael Halls-Moore, I found articles easy to read and the author has done a great job trying not to overwhelm a reader with math. I also read Michael's [first book](https://www.quantstart.com/successful-algorithmic-trading-ebook) and it's a good one for a beginner in the space like me. 
Textbooks on the topic are extremely hard for me to read. I tried [Time Series Analysis by Hamilton](http://amzn.to/2n32JKn), but haven't gotten far. 
Regarding outlier detection I mentioned - I've found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390458/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series) and [its stats counterpart](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series). By the looks of it, it's not something you can study and implement in a couple of evenings, at least not for me.

Comment: I know there's been 2 years since my question, but it looks to me that detecting outliers is a very common task. Here's a decent article with examples in Python https://towardsdatascience.com/5-ways-to-detect-outliers-that-every-data-scientist-should-know-python-code-70a54335a623