# Welford's online variance algorithm, but for Interquartile Range?

Tags: statistics, iqr, online-algorithm

### Short Version

Welford's Online Algorithm lets you keep a running value for **variance** - meaning you don't have to keep all the values (e.g. in a memory constraned system).

Is there something similar for Interquartile Range (IQR)? An online algorithm that lets me know the middle 50% range without having to keep all historical values?

### Long Version

Keeping a running average of data, where you are memory constrainted, is pretty easy:

- `Double sum`
- `Int64 count`

And from this you can compute the mean:

- `mean = sum / count`

This allows hours, or years, of observations to quietly be collected, but only take up 16-bytes.

### Welford's Algorithm for Variance

Normally when you want the variance (or standard deviation), you have to **have** all your readings, because you have to compute `reading-mean` for ***all*** previous readings:

```
Double sumOfSquaredError = 0;
foreach (Double reading in Readings)
   sumOfSquaredError += Math.Square(reading - mean);
Double variance = sumOfSquaredError / count
```

Which can add up to ***terrabytes*** of data over time, rather than taking up something like `16 bytes`.

Which is why it was nice when Welford came up with an [*online algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford%27s_online_algorithm) for computing variance of a stream of readings:

> It is often useful to be able to compute the variance in a single pass, inspecting each value ***x<sub>i</sub>*** only once; for example, when the data is being collected without enough storage to keep all the values, or when costs of memory access dominate those of computation.

The algorithm for adding a new value to the running variance is:

```
void addValue(Double newValue) {
   Double oldMean = sum / count;
   sum += newValue;
   count += 1;
   Double newMean = sum / count;

   if (count > 1)
      variance = ((count-2)*variance + (newValue-oldMean)*(newValue-newMean)) / (count-1);
   else
      variance = 0;
}
```

### How about an online algorithm for Interquartile Range (IQR)?

[Interquartile Range (IRQ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) is another method of getting the *spread* of data. It tells you how wide the middle 50% of the data is:

[image]

And from that people then generally draw a IQR BoxPlot:

[image]

Or at the very least, have the values `Q1` and `Q3`.

Is there a way to calculate the Interquartile Range **without** having to keep all the recorded values?

In other words:

> Is there something like Welford's online variance algorithm, but for Interquartile Range?

### Knuth, Seminumerical Algorithms

You can find Welford's algorithm explained in Knuth's 2nd volume *Seminumerical Algorithms*:

[image]

*(just in case anyone thought this isn't computer science or programming related)*

### Research Effort

- Stackoverflow: [Simple algorithm for online outlier detection of a generic time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390458/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series)
- Stats: [Simple algorithm for online outlier detection of a generic time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series)
- [Online outlier detection for data streams](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2076623.2076635) *(IDEAS '11: Proceedings of the 15th Symposium on International Database Engineering & Applications, September 2011, Pages 88–96)*
- Stats: [Robust outlier detection in financial timeseries](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/robust-outlier-detection-in-financial-timeseries)
- Stats: [Online outlier detection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12962/online-outlier-detection)
- [Distance-based outlier detection in data streams](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.14778/2994509.2994526) *(Proceedings of the VLDB Endowment, Volume 9, Issue 12, August 2016, pp 1089–1100)* <kbd>[pdf](https://infolab.usc.edu/Luan/Outlier/report.pdf)</kbd>
- [Online Outlier Detection Over Data Streams](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/56374415.pdf) *(Hongyin Cui, Masters Thesis, 2005)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a useful paper by Ben-Haim, and  Tom-Tov published in 2010 in the [Journal of Machine Learning Research](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/ben-haim10a/ben-haim10a.pdf)

> ### A Streaming Parallel Decision Tree Algorithm

- Short PDF: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=0667E2F91B9E0E5387F85655AE9BC560?doi=10.1.1.186.7913&rep=rep1&type=pdf
- Full paper: https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/ben-haim10a/ben-haim10a.pdf

It describes an algoritm to automatically create a histogram from a online (streaming) data, that does not require unlimited memory.

- you add a value to the history
- the algorithm dynamically creates buckets
- including bucket sizes

The paper is kind of dense (as all math papers are), but the algorithm is fairly simple.

Lets start with some sample data. For this answer i'll use digits of PI as the source for incoming floating point numbers:

| Value |
| --- |
| 3.14159 |
| 2.65358 |
| 9.79323 |
| 8.46264 |
| 3.38327 |
| 9.50288 |
| 4.19716 |
| 9.39937 |
| 5.10582 |
| 0.97494 |
| 4.59230 |
| 7.81640 |
| 6.28620 |
| 8.99862 |
| 8.03482 |
| 5.34211 |
| ... |

I will define that i want **5** bins in my histogram.

We add the first value (`3.14159`), which causes the first bin to be created:

| Bin | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 3.14159 | 1 |

The bins in this histogram don't have any width; they are purely a point:

[image]

And then we add the 2nd value (`2.65358`) to the histogram:

[image]

And we continue adding points, until we reach our arbitrary limit of 5 *"buckets"*:

[image]

That is all 5 buckets filled.

We add our 6th value (`9.50288`) to the histogram, except that means we now have **6** buckets; but we decided we only want five:

[image]

### Now is where the magic starts

In order to do the *streaming* part, and limit memory usage to *less-than-infinity*, we need to merge some of the "bins".

Look at each pair of bins - left-to-right - and see which two are closest together. Which in our case is **these** two buckets:

[image]

These two buckets are merged, and given a new **x** value dependant on their relative *heights* (i.e. counts)

- y<sub>new</sub> = y<sub>left</sub> + y<sub>right</sub> = 1 + 1 = 2
- x<sub>new</sub> = x<sub>left</sub> × (y<sub>left</sub>/y<sub>new</sub>) + x<sub>right</sub>×(y<sub>right</sub>/y<sub>new</sub>) = 3.14159×(1/2) + 3.38327×(1/2)  = 3.26243

[image]

And now we repeat.

- add a new value

[image]

- merge the two neighboring buckets that are closet to each other
- deciding on the new **x** position between based on their relative heights

[image]

Eventually giving you *(although i screwed it up as i was doing it manually in Excel for this answer)*:

[image]

### Practical Example

I wanted a histogram of 20 buckets. This allows me to extract some useful statistics. For a histogram of 11 buckets, containing 38,000 data points, it only requires 40 bytes of memory:

[image]

With these 20 buckets, i can now computer the **Probably Density Function** (PDF):

| Bin | Count | PDF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.113262834 | 3085 | 5.27630% |
| 6.091181608 | 3738 | 6.39313% |
| 10.13907062 | 4441 | 7.59548% |
| 14.38268188 | 5506 | 9.41696% |
| 18.92107481 | 6260 | 10.70653% |
| 23.52148965 | 6422 | 10.98360% |
| 28.07685659 | 5972 | 10.21396% |
| 32.55801082 | 5400 | 9.23566% |
| 36.93292359 | 4604 | 7.87426% |
| 41.23715698 | 3685 | 6.30249% |
| 45.62006198 | 3136 | 5.36353% |
| 50.38765223 | 2501 | 4.27748% |
| 55.34957161 | 1618 | 2.76728% |
| 60.37095192 | 989 | 1.69149% |
| 65.99939004 | 613 | 1.04842% |
| 71.73292736 | 305 | 0.52164% |
| 78.18427775 | 140 | 0.23944% |
| 85.22261376 | 38 | 0.06499% |
| 90.13115876 | 12 | 0.02052% |
| 96.1987941 | 4 | 0.00684% |

[image]

And with the PDF, you can now calculate the **Expected Value** (i.e. *mean*):

| Bin | Count | PDF | EV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.113262834 | 3085 | 5.27630% | 0.111502092 |
| 6.091181608 | 3738 | 6.39313% | 0.389417244 |
| 10.13907062 | 4441 | 7.59548% | 0.770110873 |
| 14.38268188 | 5506 | 9.41696% | 1.354410824 |
| 18.92107481 | 6260 | 10.70653% | 2.025790219 |
| 23.52148965 | 6422 | 10.98360% | 2.583505901 |
| 28.07685659 | 5972 | 10.21396% | 2.86775877 |
| 32.55801082 | 5400 | 9.23566% | 3.00694827 |
| 36.93292359 | 4604 | 7.87426% | 2.908193747 |
| 41.23715698 | 3685 | 6.30249% | 2.598965665 |
| 45.62006198 | 3136 | 5.36353% | 2.446843872 |
| 50.38765223 | 2501 | 4.27748% | 2.155321935 |
| 55.34957161 | 1618 | 2.76728% | 1.531676732 |
| 60.37095192 | 989 | 1.69149% | 1.021171415 |
| 65.99939004 | 613 | 1.04842% | 0.691950026 |
| 71.73292736 | 305 | 0.52164% | 0.374190474 |
| 78.18427775 | 140 | 0.23944% | 0.187206877 |
| 85.22261376 | 38 | 0.06499% | 0.05538763 |
| 90.13115876 | 12 | 0.02052% | 0.018498245 |
| 96.1987941 | 4 | 0.00684% | 0.006581183 |

Which gives:

- **Expected Value**: `27.10543`

[image]

### Cumulative Density Function *CDF*

We can now also get the **Cumulative Density Function** (CDF):

| Bin | Count | PDF | EV | CDF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.113262834 | 3085 | 5.27630% | 0.11150 | 5.27630% |
| 6.091181608 | 3738 | 6.39313% | 0.38942 | 11.66943% |
| 10.13907062 | 4441 | 7.59548% | 0.77011 | 19.26491% |
| 14.38268188 | 5506 | 9.41696% | 1.35441 | 28.68187% |
| 18.92107481 | 6260 | 10.70653% | 2.02579 | 39.38839% |
| 23.52148965 | 6422 | 10.98360% | 2.58351 | 50.37199% |
| 28.07685659 | 5972 | 10.21396% | 2.86776 | 60.58595% |
| 32.55801082 | 5400 | 9.23566% | 3.00695 | 69.82161% |
| 36.93292359 | 4604 | 7.87426% | 2.90819 | 77.69587% |
| 41.23715698 | 3685 | 6.30249% | 2.59897 | 83.99836% |
| 45.62006198 | 3136 | 5.36353% | 2.44684 | 89.36188% |
| 50.38765223 | 2501 | 4.27748% | 2.15532 | 93.63936% |
| 55.34957161 | 1618 | 2.76728% | 1.53168 | 96.40664% |
| 60.37095192 | 989 | 1.69149% | 1.02117 | 98.09814% |
| 65.99939004 | 613 | 1.04842% | 0.69195 | 99.14656% |
| 71.73292736 | 305 | 0.52164% | 0.37419 | 99.66820% |
| 78.18427775 | 140 | 0.23944% | 0.18721 | 99.90764% |
| 85.22261376 | 38 | 0.06499% | 0.05539 | 99.97264% |
| 90.13115876 | 12 | 0.02052% | 0.01850 | 99.99316% |
| 96.1987941 | 4 | 0.00684% | 0.00658 | 100.00000% |

[image]

And the CDF is where we can start to get the values i want.

The median (50th percentile), where the CDF reaches 50%:

[image]

From interpolation of the data, we can find the **x** value where the CDF is 50%:

| Bin | Count | PDF | EV | CDF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18.92107481 | 6260 | 10.70653% | 2.02579 | 39.38839% |
| 23.52148965 | 6422 | 10.98360% | 2.58351 | 50.37199% |

- t = (50-39.38839)/(50.37199-39.38839) = 10.61161/10.9836 = 0.96613
- x<sub>median</sub> = (1-t)*18.93107481 + (t)*23.52148965 = 23.366

So now we know:

- **Expected Value** (mean): `27.10543`
- **Median**: `23.366`

My original ask was the IQV - the **x** values that account from 25%-75% of the values. Once again we can interpolate the CDF:

| Bin | Count | PDF | EV | CDF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.13907062 | 4441 | 7.59548% | 0.77011 | 19.26491% |
| **12.7235** |  |  |  | **25.00000%** |
| 14.38268188 | 5506 | 9.41696% | 1.35441 | 28.68187% |
| **23.366** |  |  |  | **50.00000%** *(median)* |
| 23.52148965 | 6422 | 10.98360% | 2.58351 | 50.37199% *(mode)* |
| **27.10543** |  |  |  | **mean** |
| 28.07685659 | 5972 | 10.21396% | 2.86776 | 60.58595% |
| 32.55801082 | 5400 | 9.23566% | 3.00695 | 69.82161% |
| **35.4351** |  |  |  | **75.00000%** |
| 36.93292359 | 4604 | 7.87426% | 2.90819 | 77.69587% |

[image]

This can be continued to get other useful stats:

- Mean (aka average, expected value)
- Median (50%)
- Middle quintile (middle 20%)
- IQR (middle 50% range)
- middle 3 quintiles (middle 60%)
- 1 standard deviation range (middle 68.26%)
- middle 80%
- middle 90%
- middle 95%
- 2 standard deviations range (middle 95.45%)
- middle 99%
- 3 standard deviations range (middle 99.74%)

## Short Version

- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4c7888dd9159dc203628b0d84f0ee2f90ab4bf13/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/util/NumericHistogram.java